# OutOfMemoryError when processing Bitmaps for the second time

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm processing many Bitmaps in an activity to create an AnimationDrawable and it works perfectly (even though it uses a lot of memory). But when the user presses back and returns to the MainActivity, the memory isn't freed up.

At that moment :

- If the user then relaunches the second activity to create another
  AnimationDrawable, an OOMError will occur because the memory
  allocated to my App cannot contain two AnimationDrawables at the same
  time.
- If the user calls finish(), the app stays cached and the memory isn't freed up either.

How do I free up that memory ? I tried setting all my variables to **null**  at the end of the  second activity, I tried calling system.gc() at various moments.

This part of the code should be sufficient :

```
try {
        d = (BitmapDrawable) BitmapDrawable.createFromStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(src)), null);
        b = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
        b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 300, 450, true);
        d = new BitmapDrawable(b);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        animation.addFrame(d,1000/fps); // animation is an AnimationDrawable
```

This part of the code is in a *for* loop, it's usually being repeated about between 70 and 100 times, *animation* is thus quite "heavy". How do I get rid of it ? I want the app to "forget it" as soon as  the second activity is paused.

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606846/how-to-overcome-this-errorjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-bu/7606914#7606914

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call .recycle() method when you don't need the Bitmap object anymore:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()