# Force Close while selecting images form image gallary

Tags: android

in my program i am trying to select image from image gallary. The problem is while trying to select new imgaes continiously for two to three times i am getting "bitmap size exceeds VM budget" exception

this is my code onActivity result

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_IMAGE:
            String imagePath = getPath(data.getData());
            Savingimagepath(imagePath);
            img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any one pls help to over come this problem...

This is my log cat...

```
02-16 12:16:57.870: W/dalvikvm(2198): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:284)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:309)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:800)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at palmagent.FidelityAgent.CA.contact.onActivityResult(contact.java:249)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-16 12:16:57.870: E/AndroidRuntime(2198):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide us the error from logcat, unless we can't help you.

Comment: LOGCAT please! (I am really tired of asking for Logcat)

Comment: @SeshuVinay can u pls tell me which permission to add...

Comment: [HOPE THIS HELPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606846/how-to-overcome-this-errorjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-bu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a drawable to fit exactly a ImageView (img) sizes. If you open a large image (like photo) and set it as a drawable to ImageView it's required a lot of memory.

Just create a bitmap with really target sizes like this

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//The max size of any dimension (height or width) is 400 px
opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / 400;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, opts);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
img.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many links for the same. Try searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20vm%20budget%20exceeds)

Comment: Thanks @rash....i Already searched and tried even i cant resolve the problem.. if u know the solution pls let me know..