# cannot setvisibility in listview

Tags: android, layout, nullpointerexception

Here is to control visibility of the layout

```
if (!(imagepath[i].toString().equals("no picture"))) {
            try {
                aURL = new URL("http://www.orientaldaily.com.my/"
                        + imagepath[i]);
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();

                layout_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
            }
        }

                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
            R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, from, to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is to initialize it

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_alllatestnews);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        RelativeLayout temp = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_temp);
    LayoutInflater liInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    temp.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, null));
```

Here is the main_alllatestnews.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/layout_menu"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the main_alllatestnewslist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_temp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/background_news_list" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_alllatestnewstitle"
        android:layout_width="134px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:src="@drawable/image_loading_failed_1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When i run this, it gave me Nullpointerexception at line

```
temp.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, null)); <-- inflater still null...
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_alllatestnews);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist);
```

because `layout_image` is in layout main_alllatestnewslist

Edited:

```
        LayoutInflater liInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        yourView.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, null))
```

something like that.

;

Comment: cannot, `main_alllatestnewslist` is a part of list in the `main_alllatestnews` that why it will hit null

Comment: `SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps,
    R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, from, to);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);`
after this?

Comment: Put this on the parent layout of layout_image.

Comment: Put this on your RelativeLayout, and put some id like android:id="@+id/relative_image and on your onCreate() add it like you did on your layout_image. Then something like relativeImageLayout.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, null));

Comment: I mean parent layout of your ListView, sorry.

Comment: after `setContentView(R.layout.main_alllatestnews);` ?

Comment: I think it's temp.addView(liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_alllatestnewslist, null));
not temp.addView(inflater);

Comment: sorry, i just updated my latest code, it still hit null because `liInflater` still null

Comment: change context.getSystemService to this.getSystemService

Comment: @userlsAMonkey, any idea why still null?

Comment: What is the parent of ListView in main_alllatestnews.xml? Is it still layout_temp?

Comment: Change RelativeLayout temp = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_temp);
to RelativeLayout temp = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_content);

Comment: Oh it's LinearLayout not RelativeLayout. Did you change it?

Comment: latest update, can already no null pointer exception but got this problem `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`

Comment: I think you have to decode the bitmap, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606846/how-to-overcome-this-errorjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-bu